# Monitor changes to a database in Spring

Tags: sql-server, spring, spring-roo

I've built a spring-roo application to manage some tables in a database(SQL Server). The application is complete but one of my requirements is for Admin users to (within the application) be able to view all changes made to the database. I'm using Hibernate as my DAO. I don't know where to start with this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use audit tables and enable access only to admin users or implement role based access in your application.

[Auditing](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/8i/auditing.php) 
[Role-Based Access Control (RBAC)](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/role-based-access-control.html)